# SetFocus not going to correct textbox

Tags: excel, vba

Userform with 2 textbox entries.  I am scanning info into textbox 1 which then drops the focus to textbox 2.  Scan info into textbox 2 and data from both textboxes are entered onto worksheet correctly.  I have put a setfocus for textbox 1 but it doesn't go there.  It stays focused on textbox 2.

Originally the userform had a commandbutton but I removed it because I don't want to have to hit OK every time I enter data.

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

Dim emptyRow As Long

'Make Sheet3 active
Sheet3.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value

'Clear RO Number Box'
TextBox1.Value = ""
TextBox2.Value = ""

'Set Focus'
TextBox1.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

I expect the data to be entered upon scanning info into textbox 2 and the focus to go to textbox 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a few changes to your code:

- Don't use `TextBox2_Change()` as it would fire upon typing any char, any change made in the textbox. Instead use `TextBox2_AfterUpdate()`. That way the sub only fires upon leaving the textbox, either by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> or simply selecting any other element on the userform.
- Don't use `Activate`, and instead declare your worksheet to reference properly.
- My guess is that you would want to check if both textboxes are actually holding a value other than nothing.
- Working with userform I usually use the parent, `Me.` object refering to the different elements (but you can leave that out too)

The code would than look something like the below:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()

Dim emptyRow As Long
If Me.TextBox1.Value <> "" And Me.TextBox2.Value <> "" Then
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RO-BOX DETAILS")
        emptyRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
        Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
        Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
        Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If I use the code you provided I get 'Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range'.  Could that be the 'Me.' in front?  I didn't use 'Me.'

Comment: The code will error out on a specific line, my guess that would be `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")` leaving me thinking you probably don't have a sheet called `Sheet3`. If not this, than let me know which line.

Comment: @NormRobichaud, See my comment above your last one ^^^. The `Me.` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Actually the sheet is called 'RO-BOX DETAILS' .

Comment: SUCCESS!!! Changed it from Sheet3 to RO-BOX DETAILS and voila!  (handing you a gold star sticker now).  :)  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Use .Activate instead:

```vb
'Set Focus'
TextBox1.Activate
```

Comment: If I just change that one line, I get an audible 'ding', the code comes up with 'Private Sub TextBox2_Change()' highlighted in yellow and 'TextBox1.Activate' actually highlighted/selected (well, only the 'Activate' part was highlighted).